# Refreshing GUIZERO text with MQTT sensor readings. Not updating properly yet

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, logic, mqtt

So I'm working on a UI project for my own personal learning and enrichment.  The UI needs to be able to refresh its text with recent sensor readings being published by MQTT.  I've written up a bare bones test script to familiarize myself with the tools I'll be using, but right now my text is not refreshing itself with the new readings that are coming in.  To add to that, I'm not even sure messages are being received, when publishing a message on the same topic, nothing shows up in the console.

Here is my code:

```
from guizero import App, Text, TextBox, PushButton, Window, Box, Picture, Slider
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt 

sensorReading = ''
#######################################
def on_connect(client, userdata):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    
    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("room/temperature")
#######################################


#######################################
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global sensorReading
    sensorReading = str(message.payload)  
    print("message received " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    print("message topic=",message.topic)
    print("message qos=",message.qos)
    print("message retain flag=",message.retain)
########################################

########################################
def updateReading():
    
    client.publish('room/temperature','84')
    reading.value = sensorReading
    reading.after(1000,updateReading)
    
########################################

brokerAddress = 'redacted'
client = mqtt.Client('GG1')

print("connecting to broker")
try:
    client.connect(brokerAddress, port=1883)
    print('Connection Successful!')
except:
    print('Connection Failed')
    exit(1)

client.on_message=on_message #attach function to callback

print("Subscribing to topic","room/temperature")

app = App(title='Admin Page Test', layout='auto', height=480,width=640)
app.bg = 'white'

client.loop_start()
welcomeText = Text(app, text='Welcome!', size=40, font='Times New Roman', color='darkgreen', align='top')
clientReading = Text(app,text='Latest Reading is: ')
reading=Text(app,text='****')
reading.after(1000, updateReading)

client.loop_stop()
app.display()
```

I know this is an error in my understanding of the logic behind this system, I just don't know what part I've got wrong.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: What happens when you run this (i.e. is "message received" printed to the console?). Providing a bit more info will make it easier to help (it helps to know if the issue is MQTT related or something to do with the guizero update code). My guess is that the issue is due to the `client.loop_stop()` (the mqtt library will not process any further messages after this call - best to call this in `on_disconnect`).

Comment: Great question.  Sorry I forgot to add that part.  Nothing is spit out when I run this program.  When messages are sent, nothing is printed out.  I'm not even sure if its receiving it.

Comment: OK - then the issue will be as per my previous comment (`client.loop_stop()` is being called almost immediately after `client.loop_start()` and no messages are processed if the loop is not running). For testing just remove the `client.loop_stop()`.

Comment: Thanks.  I did that just now, however messages still aren't going through.  Seems like the on_message function is never being called.  nothing printing out of the terminal still.  I can confirm that messages are being sent though.  I'm running this on a raspberry pi 4 and when running an MQTT subscribe command with mosquitto through the terminal, messages are being received.

Comment: As you indicate that nothing at all is being printed out it appears that `on_connect` is not being called. This will be because you are not setting the callback (`client.on_connect = on_connect`). This [example](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/examples/client_sub.py) might be useful.